# Download pdf instead of opening in browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to download a tiff and pdf in my javascript but this only works for tiff files. The pdf ones open in the browser changing the view of my UI which is not desired. I am stuck with using IE 9 as that is only browser I can use in that environment.

```
<a href="<%=fileName%>" download="<%=fileName%>"><%=fileName%></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the `target="_blank"` attribute to the anchor `<a>` element:

```html
<a href="<%=fileName%>" download="<%=fileName%>" target="_blank"><%=fileName%></a>
```

This will open the PDF in a new tab/window (if that is the default browser behavior). You will not navigate away from your website. You can now save the PDF from the tab, if it doesn't automatically get downloaded.

Comment: This resolved the pdf issue. Tiff files still download which is great.